# Merge multiple csv files awk column-wise, no match

Tags: csv, awk

I'm sure this is a no-brainer and probably has been asked but I've been searching for ever now. So sorry for the dumb question!

I want to merge **multiple** CSV files:

File1

```
A, B
A, B
A, B
```

File2

```
C
C
C
```

File3

```
D
D
D
```

and I want to yield

```
A, B, C, D
A, B, C, D
A, B, C, D
```

I'm actually sorry for asking.
Thanks so much you making my life easier, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### with paste (separated by space)

```
paste -d' ' file1 file2
```

#### with awk

```
awk '{s=$0;getline < "file2";print s,$0}' file1
```

### EDIT for the requirement change:

```
kent$  awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR]?a[FNR]", "$0:$0}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print a[i]}' f1 f2 f3
A, B, C, D
A, B, C, D
A, B, C, D
```

Here you can add more files after `f1 f2 f3...`

I didn't use `getline` here because I don't know how many files do you have, if it more enough, we may have "too many open files" problem.

Comment: well both don't work; paste doesn't add a comma (with -d',' the first two files are not in the output file) and the other command joins the files like 'join'.

Comment: @user3710638 it works for your original question! you changed question, of course it won't work. If I gave another answer, you change your requirement again, it will fail again! look you changed question 8mins ago, I answered 18mins ago!

Comment: thanks for your answer but if you lock closely I have not changed my question I just clarified it. It said multiple files before. Anyhow, thanks very much.

Comment: Can the 'awk' code be adapted to combine hundreds of files (e.g., f1, f2, f3, ..., f500) without having to write out all the file names?