# concatinating .csv files column wise

Tags: csv, cmd

I have two csv files .
I want to concatenate them column wise.

I found this [Merge multiple csv files awk column-wise, no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129379/merge-multiple-csv-files-awk-column-wise-no-match...but) the commands given won't work in windows command prompt.

please help.Thank you for making my life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you could use the unix "paste" command to do this. With [Windows SUA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772343.aspx) installed, you can use paste. However, I gave it a try and as it's still unix based it doesn't like CRs in files. i.e. Unix uses LF only, Windows uses CRLF and paste will keep the CRs so you end up with carriage returns mid lines.

Writing a paste.exe to do this really wouldn't take much effort, I'm sure someone must have done that already - but I couldn't find one.

There's no single command line answer for this with windows (without using a windows version of awk or paste or maybe sed...)

So... here's a bat file to do it for you. It can handle multiple input files, with the last parameter the output file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal
if x%3 equ x goto usage

set tmpFile=%tmp%\JoiningTxt-%random%.csv
set tmpFile2=%tmp%\JoiningTxt2-%random%.csv

rem Set up the first file
copy %1 %tmpFile% > NUL
shift

:loop
rem append each file in turn
if x%2 equ x goto complete
call :Append %tmpFile% %1
shift
goto loop

:Append
rem Concatenate the 2 files together. The setlocals are to allow special chars to work ! ^ etc 
(
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
        setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        set "FirstFileLine=%%a"
        setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        set /p SecondFileLine=
        echo !FirstFileLine!,!SecondFileLine!>>%tmpFile2%
        endlocal
        endlocal
    )
)<%2
copy %tmpFile2% %1 > NUL
del %tmpFile2%
goto :EOF

:complete
copy %tmpFile% %1 > NUL
del %tmpFile%
goto end

:usage
echo Usage:
echo    %0 file1In file2In file...In fileOut
echo You must have at least 2 in files
goto end

:end 
endlocal
```