# Merge many large CSV files (in Linux)

Tags: linux, unix, csv, awk

I have ~500 CSV files, each with 5000 rows and 1000 columns (~20Mb). I would like to append them column-wise and save as a large CSV file.

A previous post partly answered this.
[Merge multiple csv files awk column-wise, no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129379/merge-multiple-csv-files-awk-column-wise-no-match)

But is there a way to do this without having to write out every file name? My file are sequentially name (e.g., X1.csv, X2.csv, X3.csv, ... , X500.csv), if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as an example, suppose that the have three such files:

```
$ cat X1.csv
A,B
A,B
A,B
$ cat X2.csv
C
C
C
$ cat X3.csv
D
D
D
```

We want to merge them, line by line, in comma-separated format, without naming each file:

```
$ paste -d, X{1..3}.csv
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```

`-d,` tells `paste` to use a comma as the delimiter when merging files.  Under `bash`, the expression `X{1..3}.csv` expands to the sequence of files in numeric order.

If you had 500 such files, the command would be:

```
 paste -d, X{1..500}.csv
```

To save the output to file:

```
 paste -d, X{1..500}.csv >merged.csv
```

Comment: Its marvellous what you just taught me, I have to merge large log files time to time and this, my friend, is treasure for me !

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nysol's mcmd. Just one line command:

```
mcat i=X*.csv o=output.csv
```

http://www.nysol.sakura.ne.jp/mcmd2/en/sect-mcat.html

Answer (score 0):

With the following shell-script you can shrink repeatedly naming files,

```
#!/bin/sh

a=500

while [ $a -gt 500 ]
do
   paste -d' ' Xtemp X$a > Xtemp
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```